# Getting error "[DeviceMotion] Event ref invalid" when running ARKit app

Tags: ios, arkit, devicemotion

I am trying to run a simple app with the ARKit and whenever I run the app, I get the following error.

> 2017-10-02 15:16:17.717533-0700 MyARKitProject [3702:2654241] [DeviceMotion] Event ref invalid

Answer (score 0):

**Restart your device** and it will work.